# Hello-Samza fails to compile

Tags: apache-samza

Executed mvn clean package as per the documentation on Hello-Samza. The build fails.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hello-samza: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.samza:hello-samza:jar:0.14.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.samza:samza-api:jar:0.14.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.samza:samza-api:jar:0.14.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.samza:samza-api:pom:0.14.1-SNAPSHOT from/to scala-tools.org (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools): Access denied to: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/org/apache/samza/samza-api/0.14.1-SNAPSHOT/samza-api-0.14.1-SNAPSHOT.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project hello-samza: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.samza:hello-samza:jar:0.14.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.samza:samza-api:jar:0.14.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue last week. If memory serves, the following steps should work around the issue:

1. Clone `Samza 0.14.1` from github
2. Build Samza and run `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal` to make the jars locally available
3. Back in the `hello-samza` project, replace all instances of `0.14.1-SNAPSHOT` with `0.14.1` in ***gradle.properties*** , ***pom.xml*** , and ***deploy.sh***
4. Build `hello-samza` normally